# All IP addresses that accessed my VPS via ssh/http(s)

Tags: networking, server, 16.04, ssh, log

I want to see that specific log file which contains all the IP's from all countries that accessed my HTTP(S) applications and SSH? I tried googling it but couldn't find any appropriate answer, I am not new to Ubuntu OS but to these core parts of OS, I am not well informed and I want these log files so I can analyze the traffic and maybe some intruders.

I have this example like, Google's Analytics Tool; one can see from which country the traffic is coming from.

**NOTE:** I have asked a precise question for experts understanding, this question is same as before but I have removed that old question and created this one.

Comment: AWstats can do the job for you IMHO.

Comment: @Jakuje How would I setup it, I only have ssh access with sudo.

Comment: There is a lot of [guides](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AWStats) around there, so it should not be a problem.